# Работа с XML файлом в собранной apk. Unity

Tags: android, unity3d

Имеется xml документ с сохранением. Во время работы приложения он должен считываться и модифицироваться. Написал для сего код, в редакторе Unity всё работает, но при сборке в apk перестает работать.

В поисках инфы наткнулся на использование `Application.persistentDataPath`, но везде оно либо просто упоминается, либо мутно написано.

Поэтому встал вопрос: как с ней работать? А именно создается ли папка с нужными файлами(с дальнейшим авто-переносом на устройство) в редакторе или надо писать скрипт для копирования этих файлов в данную директорию устройства? И уже потом  получать доступ к этим файлам. И будет ли оно работать на смарте без карты памяти?

Comment: кстати, какие ошибки выдает?

Comment: Тут я в затруднении. Оно собирается, запускается, только функционал связанный с работой c xml не пашет. А как получить какой либо лог c  билда не знаю.

Comment: _"Оно собирается, запускается, только функционал связанный с работой c xml не пашет."_  да, попробуй то что я дал в ответе.   _"А как получить какой либо лог c билда не знаю"_  https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html

Comment: Нафигачил метод [pastebin.com/HGEziwJu](http://pastebin.com/HGEziwJu)  но чет не пашет((... Походу я криворук. Ща при сборке начало кидать:

`Socket: connect failed, error: Операция на незаблокированном сокете не может быть завершена немедленно.
(0)`   |




`connect failed`   |





`Failed to connect to player ip: 192.168.100.5, port: 55080`

Comment: Это в редакторе? Или на андроиде?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Под Android можете спокойно писать данные в Application.persistentDataPath через System.IO (например, File.WriteAllText, Directory.CreateDirectory и т.д.) и читать таким же образом. Можно даже с архивами там работать через DotNetZip, если вам вдруг понадобится )

Не исключаю, что понадобится в Plugins проекта кинуть System.dll подходящей версии, но маловероятно. Если понадобится -- напишите, я вам скину подходящую.

Логи устройства смотрите через Android Device Monitor + Logcat

Answer (score 0):

Для Android нужно использовать класс WWW

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34210920/how-to-correctly-load-xml-files-on-mobile-devices-using-unity3d

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html